# When is this matrix positive semidefinite?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, probability-theory, operator-theory, positive-definite

Let us fix dimension $n$. Consider the $n \times n$ matrix
\begin{equation}
S_n=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & z & z & \cdots & z \\
\bar{z} & 1 & z & \cdots & z\\
\bar{z} & \bar{z} & 1 & \cdots & z\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
\bar{z} & \bar{z} & \bar{z} & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
When is this matrix positive?

Partial answer, if $z$ be real, say $r$, then it is easy to see that $0 \le r \le 1$. In general if $z=r e^{\imath\theta}$, then $0 \le r \le 1$ is a necessary condition, not sufficient.

The above criteria, if exists, is dimension $n$ dependent. What is the condition such that $S_n$ is positive for all $n$? I tried to construct the corresponding measure. But it seems very bizarre. Probably I am making some mistake. Please help.

Comment: Could you explain why $0 \le r \le 1$ is necessary?

Comment: That is not a answer but a necessary condition is $\text{Re}(z)>\frac{-1}{n-1}$

Comment: @Hetebrij If $r>1$, even for $n=2$ the determinant is negative. Also see the case when $z=r$ only. Then it is a circulant matrix, and eigenvalues are $(1-r)$ with multiplicity $n-1$ and $(1+(n-1)r)$ with multiplicity $1$.